# How to force AWK to stop stop applying rules?

Tags: awk

I want AWK to process my file, and change only some lines. But it prints only rule-matched lines. So I've added a `/*/ {print $0}` rule. But then I've got a duplications.

```
awk '/rule 1/ {actions 1;} /*/ {print $0}' file.txt
```

I want all lines in the output, with 'rule 1' lines changed.

Comment: show your file, expected output/result. otherwise we cannot help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make a big edit, following Ed Norton latest explanations.

- as Ed Morton pointed out, it can even be simplified as : changing lines with specific patterns, and then printing all lines

  awk '/regex1/ {actions_1} 1' file.txt

  (see his comments below for the reason why it's preferable to the one I proposed)
- For the record, there exist ways to skip the rest of the processing for the current line, such as : `continue` or `break` if it is in a loop, or `next` if it is in the main loop.

See for example : http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html#Next-Statement

Comment: Don't do that, it's completely wrong! See the other responses in this thread for the right way to do it.

Comment: I agree, I just copy/pasted his example without even checking : the actions will be done, but the line changed not printed. And the 2nd (/*/) part is wrong. I delete this so others can be selected.

Comment: I disagree: it does work, so it is not 'wrong'? Taking out 'print $0; next;' would give the same result, but it is harder to 'grok' in my opinion... here, it is simple to see how to have another  /pattern/ { action... ; next} to *not* print specific lines, etc. I'll add your way though, as it is smaller in this case.

Comment: Writing code that produces expected output is the tip of the iceberg when coding. What if in future you want to print the current line number or something with each output line? If you're printing records from multiple locations you have to go modify each location so they all do the same thing. Also the way you had it makes the reader think that printing the current record must not be what you want to do by default since you're specifically skipping the default code so it's misleading as well as harder to enhance in future if you want to do common things when printing the records.

Comment: The semi-colon before the } is redundant by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, it does now show why your way is preferable!

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `1` to the end of the script, forces `awk` to return true, which has the effect of enabling printing of all lines by default. For example, the following will print all lines in the file. However, if the line contains the words `rule 1`, only the first field of that line will be printed.

```
awk '/rule 1/ { print $1; next }1' file
```

The word `next` skips processing the rest of the code for that particular line. You can apply whatever action you'd like. I just chose to `print $1`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Or assign the result of actions 1 to $0:

```
awk '/rule 1/{$0=actions 1}1' file.txt
```

for example:

```
awk '/rule 1/{$0=$1}1' file.txt
```